# I propose the chat FAQ include a question about private messages/conversation

Tags: feature-request, chat

The chat FAQ does not currently say anything about user-to-user communication. Many people (I believe) first discovering chat.SX or chat.SO are used to IRC chats or similar systems, in which you can `/msg some_user A very personal message blah blah` - and expect this kind of a feature on the SX/SO chat. Now, regardless of whether that's a valid explanation or not, there should be, I believe, at least one FAQ items (and perhaps more than one) addressing the alternatives, i.e.:

- Creating a chatroom intended mostly for one-on-one chat as an alternative for user-to-user messaging
- Inviting a user, who is not currently in a chat room with you, to such a room
- The fact that an invitation can work only if that user has a chat server profile, and how to check whether that's the case
- A suggestion to invite to chat via a question or answer comment if all else fails

... or alternatively any body of information on this matter which the SX team deems is apropriate to communicate.

**Note:** I refrained from suggesting a specific wording for a question since I don't want this to be put down on the specific wording.

Comment: Stack Exchange chat is generally not meant to be used for private conversations, because Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a social network. If you have enough reputation, you can create a gallery chat room and give write access only to the person you want to talk with, but the room will be public anyway (so anyone can read the messages).

Comment: @Gothdo: Yes, I know that. But: 1. These things need to be in the FAQ I think and 2. Sometimes you want to discuss a point with someone who gave an answer, and comments are inappropriate; that's why there's the "lets continue in chat" automation... you don't have to wait until you hit that.

Answer (score 7):

Chat isn't really meant to be a private-messaging system. I think this FAQ would add too much weight to a use case we really *don't* want to encourage (and in many cases, do not allow).

Answer (score 3):

The very first bullet point in the Chat FAQ says:

> ...all the conversations are free, open, and public to read by anyone.

If this point weren't emphasized in the *very first* line of the FAQ, I might agree that it needs more emphasis.

---

Completely aside from whether it's a good idea to encourage private chat (it's not; see comments on your question), who exactly do you think would benefit from the additions you recommend?

To benefit, a user would have to:

1. Have the expectation of a private chat feature, and
2. Read the FAQ entries you propose.

If they read far enough to get to your proposed additions, they would have also read:

> ...all the conversations are free, open, and public to read by anyone.

How could the expectation of a private chat feature survive reading that sentence?

I don't deny that some people will read that and fail to understand it.  But it seems pointless to try to cater to such people.  If they can't understand the *first line* of the FAQ, they sure aren't going to understand more complex entries further down.